# Lagging drill in bitmap while touch in Image view

Tags: android, bitmap

I am just creating an application in which I need to drill into the bitmap, I succeed for that also but bitmap drill is lagging as I touch image view. Any help on this is really appreciated...Thanks..

Here is Main File

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
int x, y;
Bitmap background,foreground;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.mug_shot);
    foreground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.poster);

    iv.setImageBitmap(combineTwoBitmaps(background, foreground));
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x = (int) (event.getRawX()+100);
                    y = (int) (event.getY()+100);
                    System.out.println("X : "+ x +" Y : "+ y);
                    foreground = punchAHoleInABitmap(foreground);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(combineTwoBitmaps(background,foreground));
                    System.out.println("Hello this is Test2");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private Bitmap punchAHoleInABitmap(Bitmap foreground)
{
    System.out.println("Hello this is Tesyt");
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(foreground.getWidth(), foreground.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    float radius = (float)(getScreenSize().x *.35);
    float x1 = (float) ((x*.5) + (radius * .5));
    float y1 = (float)  ((y*.5) + (radius * .5));
    System.out.println("X1 : "+ x1 +" Y1 : "+ y1);
    canvas.drawCircle(x1, y1, 50, paint);
    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap combineTwoBitmaps(Bitmap background, Bitmap foreground) {
    Bitmap combinedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), background.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combinedBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, paint);
    return combinedBitmap;
}

private Point getScreenSize() {
    WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_MOVE` is called many times when users slide the screen. This means you will create quite amount of bitmaps in short time.

With `GestureDetector` you can detect exact one slide/swipe/fling.

Comment: But I need to show drill real-time like as I continue to move my finger It will continue to drill on bitmap is it possible with the GestureDetector????

Comment: You can't that way. You need to create custom view: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html You can have one bitmp, then draw bitmap and your circle (or whatever) on canvas in onDraw. Animate circle without creating bitmaps.